# Gorm not giving correct inserted record's primary key ID

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am using GORM with GO.

I have an entity User

```
type User struct {
    Id int `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    gorm.Model
}
```

My Create record code is

```
user := User{}
user.Name = "Afzal"
DB.Create(&user)
```

Now as per Doc `user.ID` should return inserted data's primary key

But it's returning 0 which is the default value when struct User was initialized.

Comment: You are embedding gorm.Model which already includes a ID field with primary  key and auto increment properties.

Comment: @DiptoMondal No auto increment looking [at the source](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/model.go), unless `primarykey` checks the field type, and gorm turns a (u)int + primaryKey into autoincrement implicitly. It's possible gorm does that, although technically `0` is a valid uint value, and could be argued to be a valid ID value

Comment: Yeah I wanted to say that he can rely on the default gorm.Model for what he is trying to achieve with `Id int `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"` and also will be able to get the expected result  from `user.ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.Id` will have the correct value, because you've added that field and tagged it as being the primary key. `user.ID` actually accesses `user.Model.ID`. This, too, has the primaryKey tag, but it's superseded by the `Id` field on your `User` type.

You've embedded the `gorm.Model` type (as per the docs, I imagine), but that means your `User` type actually looks like this:

```
User{
    Id    int
    Name  string
    gorm.Model{
        ID        uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
        CreatedAt time.Time
        UpdatedAt time.Time
        DeletedAt DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
    }
}
```

So when you look at `user.ID`, you're accessing the embedded `ID` field. Either check the `Id` field (lower-case `d`), or remove the `Id` field you've added, and rely on the `ID` from the embedded `Model`.

If you do want to keep your own `Id` field, I think the `gorm.Model` is right to make it a `uint`. If you're needing to faff around with negative ID elements in your data, you're probably doing something wrong... I've seen negative ID's being used, but every time I saw it happen, it was some absolutely horrible hack.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is working for now as I have removed my Id and relying on GORM ID. But wanted to confirm one more thing as I am also using this struct to implement multiple methods for an interface. Will it create any problems in future?

Comment: @AfzalKhan It shouldn't. Embedding `gorm.Model` is optional anyway (just convenience to add common fields to your models). It _might_ be an issue if you're implementing something like the error interface (`Error() string`) on a data model that is also used as a one-to-one relational model or something, but you'd have to check the gorm source/docs to be sure. A badly implement `NullValue` (that returns `false` even when valid) might be an issue, too, but then your implementation is bugged, so it's not due to the interface itself :)